# Parse JavaScript functions not responding in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, parse-platform

I have created a parse register and login, and where the javascript functions work and respond well in Firefox and Chrome, but does not seem to respond in internet explorer.

Below is the Parse Javascript functions:

```
Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");

angular.module('AuthApp', [])
.run(['$rootScope', function($scope) {
  $scope.scenario = 'Sign up';
  $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();

  $scope.signUp = function(form) {
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("First Name", form.fname);
    user.set("Last Name", form.lname);
    user.set("password", form.password);
        user.set("email", form.email);

    user.signUp(null, {
      success: function(user) {
window.location = 'myprofile.php'
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Unable to sign up:  " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });    
  };

  $scope.logIn = function(form) {
    Parse.User.logIn(form.lemail, form.lpassword, {
      success: function(user) {
  window.location = 'myprofile.php'
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Unable to log in: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.logOut = function(form) {
window.location = 'index.html'
  };
}]);
```

Below is the body of the html:

```
<body ng-app="AuthApp">
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" >
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="label"> Email </label> <br>
              <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="input"  ng-model="user.lemail">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label id="label"> Password </label> <br>
              <input type="password"  class="form-control" id="input" ng-model="user.lpassword" >
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="signin" ng-click="logIn(user)">Login</button> <br>
           <label id="label"> <input type="checkbox" id="keepin"> Keep me signed in </label>
          </form>

  </div>

      </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
<div>
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered col-fixed"><div class="item"><div class="content">


        </div></div></div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered col-fixed"><div class="item"><div class="content" id="signupBox">

  <form name="contactform" method="post"  class="form-horizontal" role="form"  ng-show="scenario == 'Sign up'">
<h1 id="headingSignup"> NEW? </h1>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="inputfirstName" placeholder="First Name" id="signupformInput" ng-model="user.fname" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="inputlastName" placeholder="Last Name" id="signupformInput" ng-model="user.lname">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control"  name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address" id="signupformInput" ng-model="user.email" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                  <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="password" placeholder="Password" id="signupformInput" ng-model="user.password">
                                </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="entryCode" placeholder="Entry code" id="signupformInput">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="signinformButtons" ng-click="signUp(user)">
                                        Join
                                    </button>
                                    <br>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="signinformButtons">
                                       About us
                                    </button>
                                            </form>
            </div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Which versions of IE and Angular are you using?

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the developer console?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Were currently using Version 11 of IE, and im not sure of the angular version, but I was experiencing this issue without angular being referenced, so i think the issue mainly derives from Parse Javascript.

Comment: I did actually recieve error in IE developer console when trying to run the function by attempting to log in. The error is as follow: "Unable to get property 'getItem' of undefined or null reference" for the following line: " $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();"